# Carregar JWT signature key a partir de uma base dinâmica

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth2, jwt

Eu implementei um Authorization Server utilizando `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` e o usuarios e clientes são configurados a partir da implementação dos serviços `UserDetailsService` e `ClientDetailsService` que recolhem as informações necessárias no banco de dados.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2JwtAuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        private  UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        private AppClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

        @Override
        public void configure(final AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
            oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {          
            clients.withClientDetails(clientDetailsService);
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
            final DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
            defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
            defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
            return defaultTokenServices;
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            final TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
            tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter()));

            endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
            .reuseRefreshTokens(false)
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }

        @Bean
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
        }

        @Bean
        public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
            final JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
            converter.setSigningKey("123");

            return converter;
        }

        @Bean
        public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
            return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
        }

        @Bean
        public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
}
```

O Authorization Server está funcionando devidamente, mas gostaria que a signature key setada no método `accessTokenConverter()`, fosse carregada dinâmicamente, quando eu receber a requisição para um novo Token, gostaria de acessar o banco de dados e modificar a Signing Key neste momento e devolver o Token com essa nova assinatura modificada, atualmente ela está apenas sendo configurada no momento que a aplicação é iniciada.